# Erro ao converter JSON. (com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException)

Tags: java, json, gson

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que precisa se comunicar com uma loja online, toda a comunicação é feita via requisições HTTP e tem como resposta um JSON.

Apresenta o erro `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException`. Já conferi várias vezes e até usando sites que conferem a sintaxe do JSON e a sintaxe parece estar correta.

Desenvolvi um exemplo mínimo e executável, substituindo toda a parte das requisições HTTP por uma string que armazena o JSON para simplificar já que as demais partes não apresentam erros e possuem dados que não posso passar.

Minha dúvida é como resolver este erro `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException` no meu programa. (Segue log de erros)

Json.class

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O resultado é exibido no console.");


                String strJson = "[\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "“id”: 1,\n" +
                "“createdAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”,\n" +
                "“updatedAt”: “2016-12-27T14:57:39-02:00”,\n" +
                "“erpId”: “Armazém 1”,\n" +
                "“name”: “Armazém Revenda”,\n" +
                "“priority”: 1,\n" +
                "“branch”: {\n" +
                "“id”: 1,\n" +
                "“erpId”: “Filial 1”,\n" +
                "“name”: “Filial 1”,\n" +
                "“documentId”: “”,\n" +
                "“createdAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”,\n" +
                "“updatedAt”: “2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00”\n" +
                "},\n" +
                "“default”: true,\n" +
                "“quantity”: 1\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "]";

        List<Warehouses> lista = JSONtoList(strJson);

        for(Warehouses w: lista) {
            System.out.println(w.getId());
            System.out.println(w.isDef());
        }

    }

    public static List<Warehouses> JSONtoList(String strJson) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Warehouses>>() {
        }.getType();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").create();
        List<Warehouses> lista = gson.fromJson(strJson, type);

        return lista;
    }

}
```

Branch.class

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Branch {

    private int id;
    private String erpId;
    private String name;
    private String documentId;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updateAt;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getErpId() {
        return erpId;
    }
    public void setErpId(String erpId) {
        this.erpId = erpId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }
    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    public Date getUpdateAt() {
        return updateAt;
    }
    public void setUpdateAt(Date updateAt) {
        this.updateAt = updateAt;
    }

}
```

Warehouses.class

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Warehouses {

    private int id;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updateAt;
    private String erpId;
    private String name;
    private int priority;
    private Branch branch;
    @SerializedName("default")
    private boolean def;
    private int quantity;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
    public Date getUpdateAt() {
        return updateAt;
    }
    public void setUpdateAt(Date updateAt) {
        this.updateAt = updateAt;
    }
    public String getErpId() {
        return erpId;
    }
    public void setErpId(String erpId) {
        this.erpId = erpId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    public Branch getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }
    public boolean isDef() {
        return def;
    }
    public void setDef(boolean def) {
        this.def = def;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Erro

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 4 column 29 path $[0].null
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:942)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at json.Json.JSONtoList(Json.java:56)
    at json.Json.main(Json.java:42)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 4 column 29 path $[0].null
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:491)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    ... 4 more
```

Adicionar a Lib Gson! [Baixar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar)

Comment: Essa string ai é seu arquivo json? Faltou a classe q converte json.

Comment: Sim, é o json. Coloquei o método que converte o json em lista em Json.class. O nome dele é JSONtoList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema são essas aspas do seu json, você não notou que o java nem pediu pra você escapar elas? Porque não são aspas válidas, por isso o json não consegue formatar. Troquei todas por aspas duplas(") e o código rodou sem problemas.

```
    String strJson = "[" +
    "{" +
    "\"id\": 1," +
    "\"createdAt\": \"2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00\"," +
    "\"updatedAt\": \"2016-12-27T14:57:39-02:00\"," +
    "\"erpId\": \"Armazém 1\"," +
    "\"name\": \"Armazém Revenda\"," +
    "\"priority\": 1," +
    "\"branch\": {" +
    "\"id\": 1," +
    "\"erpId\": \"Filial 1\"," +
    "\"name\": \"Filial 1\"," +
    "\"documentId\": \"\"," +
    "\"createdAt\": \"2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00\"," +
    "\"updatedAt\": \"2016-12-27T10:58:13-02:00\"" +
    "}," +
    "\"default\": true," +
    "\"quantity\": 1" +
    "}" +
    "]";
```

<kbd><[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Lembrando que é preciso escapar com `\`.

Comment: Uma coisa tão simples que me deu a maior surra. E olha que em dois sites que validei o json ele passou sem problemas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.